# Apex Charts -- Pie chart gets stuck in "loading" state after API call and won't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apexcharts

I am building a pie chart to display JSON data using Javascript, jQuery, and ApexCharts.js.

The Apex Charts [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/update-charts-from-json-api-ajax/) specifies that when working with dynamically updating data, it is best to first create and append an empty chart and then update it once I have new data. I have successfully built several charts this way - the "empty" chart just displays "loading..." text in the body, and then once the update function is invoked, the chart redraws with the data as expected. Easy.

However, when working with [Pie/Donut](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/pie-charts/simple-pie-chart/#) charts, I'm encountering an issue where the chart freezes in the "loading..." state. I've spent days messing around with it and console logging everything line by line. It seems like everything is working exactly as it should be each step of the way, but then the pie chart stays stuck in "loading..." even once the update function is invoked and the new data is returned. Sometimes I can see the data flash on the screen for a moment, but then the chart just reverts back to empty state.

I don't think this is a sequence of events issue, since I'm already using async/await to make sure I have the data before I call the function to update and display the chart.

I created a minimal reproduction of the problem where you can try commenting out the API call; here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/JjpddvP?editors=1011), and code snippets are below. If you remove the line that invokes the API call (lines 75/76 on the codepen), everything works fine. As soon as you add the API call into the mix, the chart stops updating. Also, we're not even using the returned data in this demo - I'm just passing in dummy data and making an API call for the purpose of demonstrating the issue.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- jQuery Scripts -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@2.1.7/dist/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Apex Charts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

    <!-- JS Add-on Scripts -->
    <script type="module" src="./test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="go-btn">DISPLAY CHART</button>

    <div id="chart">


    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
/////////////////////////
// Create empty charts
//////////////////////////

// On page load, attach click listener to button. The button, when clicked, will invoke a function to create and display the pie chart
$(function () {
  $("#go-btn").on("click", () => {
    populateChart();
  });
});

// API Call just for demo purposes, not actually using any of the returned data
async function getDataAjax() {
  // Local Variables
  const getURL = "https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts";
  let result;


  $.LoadingOverlay("show");

  try {
    result = await $.ajax({
      url: getURL,
      type: "GET",
    });

    $.LoadingOverlay("hide");

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

// A function to create an empty chart that will eventually get updated with data
async function createEmptyChart() {
  var options = {
    series: [],
    chart: {
      id: "pie-chart",
      width: 380,
      type: "pie",
      redrawOnWindowResize: false,
    },
    noData: {
      text: "loading...",
    },
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 200,
          },
          legend: {
            position: "bottom",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
  chart.render();
}

// A function to update the empty chart with data
//! COMMENT OUT LINES 78/79 AND EVERYTHING WILL WORK PROPERLY

async function populateChart() {
  await createEmptyChart();
  // Make API call for data -- just making the API call causes the chart to freeze in "loading..." state
  let data = await getDataAjax();
  console.log(data);

  // Update chart with dummy data
  ApexCharts.exec("pie-chart", "updateSeries", [23, 46, 18, 94]);

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusing title, I just fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `updateSeries` not working if there is not initial `series`, after this change in `createEmptyChart` chart renders normarly.

```
var options = {
  series: [{
    data:[0]
  }],
...
```

Other solution is to use `updateOptions` instead of `updateSeries`.